# Ajax returns the whole web page as response in tagit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have an ajax function that sends data to a php codeigniter script and returns the whole page. I need suggetions from the response for tagit. Please suggest a solution. Thanks

Here is the code

Ajax call

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
                      $("#allTags").tagit({
                        tagSource: function(search, showChoices) {
                          $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: base_url + "beep/suggetions",
                            data: "search=" + search.term,
                            //contentType: "application/json",
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function(choices) {
                              alert(choices);
                              showChoices(choices);
                            }
                          });
                        }
                      });
            });
```

Controller function

```
  public function suggetions(){
      header('Content-type: application/json');
      $arr=Array();
      $arr[] = 'tag111';
      $arr[] = 'tag222';
      $arr[] = 'tag333';
      echo json_encode($arr);
  }
```

Comment: Is your url correct?

Comment: @FairyDancer  yes

Comment: did you check result coming from the url manually without using ajax script. What I mean is `http://localhost/beep/suggetions` by entering the url did you get result correctly ?

Comment: What is work of "showChoices" function?

Comment: @FairyDancer the url http://localhost/beep/suggetions also give me the full webpage as its result

Comment: @Anshul it is for tag suggetions

Comment: can you show the screenshot of your screen while entering the url... I need to see, then only i can find what the exact problem is